# How to use order by after group by sql

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

[image: start table]

and I need to group by and order on positionNr.

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT campus,
    building,
    department,
    officeNr,
    officeName,
    positionNr,
FROM organizationStruct
group by campus, building, department, officeNr, officeName, positionNr
order by positionNr
```

But I obtain something like this:

[image: result table]

But what I want is a result like this:

[image: expected result]

Please can you help to understand where is the problem on the query?

Comment: If I understand correct from your expected output you want to order by campus rather than positionNr. Also group by without aggregate makes no sense

Comment: just remove group by, this will solve your problem

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? Do you want SELECT DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your expected result, it seems that:
1- You don't need a group by, we use group by for aggregate functions.
2- You are ordering by campus first, positionNr after

Try this query

```
SELECT campus,
building,
department,
officeNr,
officeName,
positionNr,
FROM organizationStruct
order by campus, positionNr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SELECT campus, building, department, officeNr, officeName, positionNr
    FROM organizationStruct
    ORDER BY positionNr
```